# Visual Basic - Getting basic information about another program

Tags: vba

Alright, I am currently working on an Updater which is updating several files such as executable and drivers. I don't want to replace every single file every time I push an update and rather just replace the file that is actually getting updated. An easy way would be reading the Version of the program but I don't know how to read the required information. I went through IO.File but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for looping through a folder's files.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim varFile As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim objShell
Dim objDir

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objDir = objShell.Namespace("C:\DIRECTORY_OF_FILES_HERE\")

For Each varFile In objDir.Items
   Debug.Print objDir.GetDetailsOf(varFile, 156) ' 156 = File Version
Next

' Use this to see the numbers of all the attributes, e.g. 156 = File Version
'For i = 0 To 300
'   Debug.Print i, objDir.GetDetailsOf(objDir.Items, i)
'Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks thats excactly what I have been searching for!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate file that will indicate the version of each individual files you will be updating. This is generally how I do things.

Say you have a file for this, we'll call it "version.txt". This is ideally what you would set it up like this: (you could do a lines format or javascript, whatever you feel most comfortable with)

```
    mainapplication.version = 2.1
```

So, in your updater method, you would set the latest version as something like 2.2.

```
    Dim alatestVersion As Double
    alatestVersion = 2.2
```

You could then parse the text file and create a method to check if the component is of the latest version or not. Following this, if mainapplicationVersion != alatestVersion then [update].

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm I get your Idea and i think its fairly good but isn't there a way to kind of load the file and read the necessary information?

Comment: I see what you are saying. You could make a function to compare the current file and the latest file to see if they are identical.

Comment: Use [this](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=574) as a reference, should be straight forward.